# Error in calculation while looping through the data

Tags: r, parentheses, extra

I have a dataframe with 3 variables and I am trying to calculate how many chares can be purchased with £100 in the first year when the company was listed

The data looks like

YEAR_END COMPANY_NUMBER CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE   NUMBER_OF_SHARES
31/12/2002   22705              7.5                 0
31/12/2003   22705              6.55                0
31/12/2004   22705              6.55                0
31/12/2005   22705              NA                  0
31/12/2006   22705              NA                  0
31/12/2007   22705              NA                  0
31/12/2008   22705              NA                  0
31/12/2004  11356069           1.09                 0
31/12/2002  SC192761           2.42                 0
31/12/2003  SC192761            0.9                 0
31/12/2004  SC192761             NA                 0
31/12/2005  SC192761             NA                 0
31/12/2006  SC192761             NA                 0
31/12/2007  SC192761             NA                 0
31/12/2002  10395804           1.04                 0
31/12/2003  10395804           1.04                 0
31/12/2004  10395804             NA                 0
31/12/2003   5625107           0.02                 0
31/12/2004   5625107             0                  0

The code I have written is:

```
 for (i in 1:(nrow(PLC_Return)-1))
 if (i == 1)
   {
   NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 100/is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
   } else if
   (is.na(PLC_Return[i, 1]) == is.na(PLC_Return[i + 1, 1])
   {
    NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i]=0  
   }   else 
   {
   NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 100/is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
   }
```

basically it is that for the first company year calculate the shares purchased. Then in the send year I don't need the calculation.

```
 for (i in 1:(nrow(PLC_Return)-1))
 if (i == 1)
   {
   NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 100/is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
   } else if
   (is.na(PLC_Return[i, 1]) == is.na(PLC_Return[i + 1, 1])
   {
    NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i]=0  
   }   else 
   {
   NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 100/is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
   }
```

I get an error
Error: unexpected '}' in "       }"

> ```
>    {
> ```

- ```
     NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 100/is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
  ```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Ahson

Answer (score 0):

May be a proper indentation and for loop block could help

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(PLC_Return)-1))
{
      if (i == 1)
         {
              NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 
              1000/is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
          } 
      else if((is.na(PLC_Return[i, 1]) == is.na(PLC_Return[i + 1, 1]))   {
           NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i]=0  
   }   
       else 
   {
               NUMBER_OF_SHARES[i] = 
             1100is.na(CLOSE_SHARE_PRICE[i])
   }
}
```

Comment: Well I did posted from mobile so, indentation might not be proper